# jQuery slider isn't working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using Flexslider from WooThemes to power a slideshow on a client's website and it's working fine, apart from in IE8 (Maybe lower too but I'm not developing for anything lower than 8).

I've used the same plugin on other sites and it worked in IE8 and I'm a bit of a loss as to why it's not working now.

[This is the reference URL](http://stage.purenine.com/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT :** It appears to just be the slide transitions that aren't working as the inline styles applied by the plugin are being applied in IE8...

Comment: Why do you worry for IE8, we are now in IE10 and 2 years after another verion? It's free, your visitor will update...

Comment: Slider you used works on "transform", Which is CSS3 property and not supported in IE8 its also not working in IE9...Please share the links, where its working for IE8.

Comment: @jacouh It's not my decision unfortunately, my client insists IE8 be supported

Comment: @Tushar the demo version is working fine in IE8 and 9 [link](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) so why isn't it working on my client's server?

Comment: @jacouh We are now in IE11

Comment: @Eugene Xa, I'm late...